# Where to put 'soon'

Tags: articles, word-order, time

Is the sentence below incorrect?

> Please give her a box that you will **soon** receive.

I was advised to put 'soon' at the end of the sentence. But I read somewhere that I can put an adverb before a verb when they are highly related.

Answer (score 2):

> Please give her a box that you will soon receive.

and

> Please give her a box that you will receive soon.

are both correct. You are right about the adverb and verb being highly related. Either option is correct. I have a preference for "receive soon" but the other one isn't wrong at all, and it's possible other English speakers would have a different preference anyway.

However, the sentence is almost certainly talking about a specific box. So you want "the", not "a".

> Please give her **the** box that you will soon receive.